# Jquery Iframe src to autoplay video

Tags: jquery, iframe, video-streaming

I have a Vimeo embeded video using their code(iframe) on my site.

```
    <iframe id="movie" src="" width="979" height="416" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Now what I want to do is change the src through jquery like this:

on load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#movie').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/33971928?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1;');
});
```

the video shows up fine but it doesn't autoplay.  If i put that line inside the iframe source without jquery it works and autoplays.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **not** using HTML entities in your URL:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/33971928?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1;
```

Comment: excellent! thank you didn't know html entities would cause that.